# Copy text between multiple { } per line into a textfile

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

i need a solution to extract text in the following way:

*input.txt*

```
"description": "{A, 0}, {B, 1200}, {C, 543}",
```

(and so on)

This is from a larger JSON file:

```json
{
  "cover_path": "n/a",
  "description": "{A, 0}, {B, 1200}, {C, 543}",
  "duration": 541234,
  "title": "16.05.2013 - Title"
}
```

Expected output:

A.txt

```
A, 0
```

B.txt

```
B, 1200
```

C.txt

```
C, 543
```

Comment: Is the input JSON or YAML or some other structured document format? If so, please post a syntactically correct example document.

Comment: @Kusalananda 

tag.txt contains:

`{
    "cover_path": "n/a",
    "description": "{A, 0}, {B, 1200}, {C, 543}",
    "duration": 541234,
    "title": "16.05.2013 - Title",
}`

I strip it down with

`grep "description" tag.txt > description.txt`

to

`"description": "{A, 0}, {B, 1200}, {C, 543}",` 

and write it to description.txt
It all is done with bash.

Now i need a txt-file for every entry.

a.txt -> A, 0
b.txt -> B, 1200
c.txt -> C, 543

I'm able to format the input of tag.txt as i like. Maybe that would make it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

description=$(cat "large.json" | jq -r ".description")
readarray -d "{" -t desc_array <<<"${description}"
for part in "${desc_array[@]}"; do
    [[ -z "${part}" ]] && continue
    part="${part/%$'\n'/}"
    part="${part/\}/}"
    part="${part// /}"
    part="${part/%,/}"
    IFS="," read -r basename content <<<"${part}"
    printf "%s, %s" "${basename}" "${content}" > "${basename}.txt"
done
```